# Unable to consume STS credentials generated by Lambda for connecting to IoT endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-iot, aws-sts

I am unable to connect to AWS IoT endpoint, using STS credentials (AssumeRoleUsingWebIdentity) generated by AWS Lambda.

It is throwing me *AMQJS0008I Socket closed* error

I tried connecting to the same endpoint with the STS credentials (AssumeRoleUsingWebIdentity) and roles generated via AWS CLI & it worked.

But, not sure why this is not working with Lambda.

```
const params = {
        DurationSeconds: 43000, 
        RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::123456789123:role/TestRole',
        RoleSessionName: "IoT-User", 
        WebIdentityToken: "<token>",
        Policy: "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"Stmt1\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Action\":\"s3:ListAllMyBuckets\",\"Resource\":\"*\"}]}"
    };

    const data = await sts.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity(params).promise();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is now solved ! When using AssumeRoleUsingWebIdentity for generating STS credentials, if you provide Role and Policy both then, function will provide the STS credentials with lowest possible privileges from both of them.

I was under assumption that, custom policy with additional privileges will be injected to the STS credentials. While that's not the case.

I guess this should be documented somewhere in AWS Documentation.